# Newtonian Size - Where to find in Blender 2.8

Tags: particles, physics

I am trying to change the size of my leaf particle through Physics settings in the Particle System. In older Blender versions there used to be the size setting right under Physics -> Newtonian. Or if not the Advanced feature enabled it was under Render settings. Where did it go in Blender 2.8? Any help is highly appreciated :-)! Thank you in advance!

[image: ParticleSettings-Render][image: RenderSettings-Render][image: OriginalSizeFeature under PhysicsSettings in Particles]

Comment: In blender 2.8, particle "Size" is under "Render" panel and now, it is renamed as "Scale".

Comment: Hi @3DSinghVFX , thank you for the answer but I checked and couldn't find "Scale" neither under Particles -> Render nor the normal Render Tab. I will also Edit my question to attach the according screenshots. You have any other ideas or could attache a screenshot of your Blender layout to show me?

Comment: My previous answer was for particles. For hairs, "Radius Scale" is under "Hair Shape" panel.

Comment: Hi @3DSinghVFX, thanks again for getting back. I tried it but it doesn't change the size of my hair. I am looking for the Newtonian Size feature. It used to be there, see one more screenshot attached. What I did: Applied to a MoCap a hair particle system, to which I connected a leaf shape and now I want the leaf to show up bigger and not totally skinny :-D ... but the feature is missing. I also looked at some former discussions about the same feature when people changed to version 2.79 but it is not there either ... stick with me please :-)

Comment: You are right, Newtonian Size feature is not available in blender 2.79 (latest build) and in blender 2.8. But you can change the particle or hair size with the "Scale" option in Render panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the **size** of particles or hair (object) in **Render panel**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @3DSinghVFX: I had to change from Path to Object and finally the Scale option showed! You made my day, thanks again :-)!

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.8 particle size is under *Viewport Display*!